# OpenWRT, iptables and ipset rule for redirect destination host to another ip?

Tags: networking, iptables, openwrt

How to redirect destination host to another ip?

This rule don't work:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -m set --match-set redirectsites src,dst -j DNAT --to-destination ipaddr
```

Could you explain, what is wrong on the rule above?

Thank you for your answers.